# Get data from a pointer's row in Parse (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a pointer named "Parent" in my class, "ComparablePhotos", which points to another class, "NewLog".  I am trying to get the data (Address, ObjectId, Lat) from the row in NewLog that Parent points to.  How do I do this using query1.includeKey provided?

Code:

```
    var query1 = PFQuery(className: "ComparablePhotos")
    query1.includeKey("Parent")
    //get NewLog[address], NewLog[lat], and NewLog[objectId] using "Parent" pointer
```

ComparablePhotos class:
[image]

NewLog class:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this helps you out at all...you probably will have to change some of the objects to exactly fit your words from the parse database.hopefully that will steer you in the right direction

```
var query1 = PFQuery(className:"NewLog")
query1.includeKey("Parent")
query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in


    if let objects = objects {

      for object in objects {

      var address = object["address"]  as! String
      var lat =  object["lat"]  as! String
      var objectId = object["objectId"] as! String
```

this is how i query a role, which is similar to a pointer query...

```
var roleQuery = PFRole.query()
roleQuery!.whereKey("name", equalTo: "admin")
roleQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() { (roleObject: PFObject?, error) -> Void in

  var adminRole = roleObject as! PFRole

  adminRole.users.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

    if let adminUsers = (users as? [PFUser])  {
```

Comment: I tried your first code and it returned nil... Not returning anything from the NewLog class.

Comment: i edited it so that it will query your NewLog class, you will make two separate queries for each class.. so do this exact same code for your comparable photos class.

Comment: Thank you... I am still confused unfortunately, I am new to Swift :/

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579733/query-row-in-parse-using-pointer-ios .

Comment: But how you make the connectio between the comparablephotos and newlog classes??