# Query row in Parse using Pointer (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get a row of data from the class, ComparablePhotos in Parse.  However, the only row from ComparablePhotos I want to get, is the row whose pointer, column "Parent", has the same objectId (in NewLog) as a string variable I have, markerObjectId, ex: inI9tJ8x7.  I would use the simple query in ComparablePhotos where key "Parent" is equal to markerObjectId, but Parent is a pointer, and not a string. 
 How do I grab the row from ComparablePhotos whos whose pointer, column "Parent", has the same NewLog objectId as a markerObjectId?    Something along the lines like if the ComparablePhotos row's Parent.objectId == markerObjectId, store that row into a variable?

ComparablePhotos class in Parse.  "Parent" column is a pointer.
[image]

NewLogClass.  The pointer points here.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var newLogObjectsArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()

    //newLogObjectId is a string im comparing to, ex: inI9tJ8x7
    newLogObjectId = objectIdArray[markerIndex]

    var picquery = PFQuery(className:"ComparablePhotos")
    picquery.selectKeys(["objectId", "Images", "LocationType", "Parent"])
    picquery.includeKey("Parent.objectId")
    picquery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    picquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (NewLog, error) -> Void in

        //Here prints are all our rows from the class, ComparablePhotos.
        println("NewLog")

        if let NewLog = NewLog as? [PFObject] {
            for log in NewLog {
                //Here are all our rows from the class, NewLog.
                var ParseNewLogClass: PFObject = (log["Parent"] as? PFObject)!
                self.newLogObjectsArray.append(ParseNewLogClass)
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the pointer to an object instead of the string id of the object?

Comment: No I have not.. How would I do that?

Comment: Your query doesn't actually have a check of the parent currently. And you would create an object placeholder with the id (there is an api for that)

Comment: I thought it does check Parent.. I have picquery.selectKeys and one of them is "Parent"...  I'm sorry I don't follow, this is my first app in Parse and in swift, so I am very new.  Could you please provide a code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code:

```
var picquery = PFQuery(className:"ComparablePhotos")
picquery.selectKeys(["objectId", "Images", "LocationType", "Parent"])
picquery.includeKey("Parent.objectId")
picquery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

- creates a query for `ComparablePhotos`
- asks for a limited set of data fields to be returned (`selectKeys`)
- asks for an associated object to be included in the response (incorrectly) (`includeKey`)
- orders the results

What you actually want is to get the full object details in the response and to filter by a specified parent. To do that you need to create a `PFObject` for the parent object id details you have (see `objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:`) and then use `whereKey:equalTo:`.

```
var picquery = PFQuery(className:"ComparablePhotos")
picquery.includeKey("Parent")
picquery.whereKey("Parent", equalTo:parentObject)
picquery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

Comment: I have attempted and I feel I am almost at success.      I have created a PFObject, pointer.  However, I am generating an error: "Cannot invoke whereKey with an argument list of type, String"... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code:
 let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"ComparablePhotos", objectId: newLogObjectId)
        picquery.whereKey("Parent")
        picquery.includeKey("Parent", equalTo:pointer)
        picquery.orderByAscending("createdAt")

Comment: did you by chance mix up the whereKey and the includeKey in your code?

Comment: THANK YOU WAIN!  I cannot emphasize how much I appreciate your help.  I was stuck on this for a week, and was almost about to give up.  You are appreciated!

Comment: P.S the whereKey and includeKey are mixed up in your code, so maybe you could update it so it doesnt confuse others that look at this :D

Comment: No prob!  Thanks for the help again Wain.